# Syntax error, creating database

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create database android_api and table users but I am getting error

```
#1064 - Something is wrong in your syntax near 'use android_api

create table 'users'(
   id int(11) NOT NULL primary KEY AU' w linii 3
```

Here is the code

```
create database android_api

use android_api

create table users(
   id int(11) NOT NULL primary KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
   unique_id varchar(23) not null unique,
   name varchar(50) not null,
   email varchar(100) not null unique,
   encrypted_password varchar(80) not null,
   salt varchar(10) not null,
   created_at datetime,
   updated_at datetime null
);
```

Comment: Um.. here - `updated_at datetime null` ? you don't need to give null there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should separate each SQL statement with `;`, otherwise your syntax is incorrect.

Here is the correct syntax:

```
create database android_api;

use android_api;

create table users(
   id int(11) NOT NULL primary KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
   unique_id varchar(23) not null unique,
   name varchar(50) not null,
   email varchar(100) not null unique,
   encrypted_password varchar(80) not null,
   salt varchar(10) not null,
   created_at datetime,
   updated_at datetime null
);
```

In your code what you did was actually:

```
create database android_api use android_api
```

(Which is not a valid `CREATE` statement).

Comment: hmm now I have error A symbol name was expected! near name
unexpected beginning of statement near 50
Unrecognized statement type neae not null
name varchar(50) not null,

Comment: are you using mysql? which version? how exactly you run these queries?

Comment: SQL it's phpMyAdmin php ver 5.5

Comment: and you still didn't answer what version of **mysql** you are using

Comment: My hosting using MariaDB version 10

Comment: syntax should be ok. I just checked on mysql 5.6 (which is same engine as mariadb 10) and it works. are you sure you don't have any other errors there?

Comment: Now i got only error (red circle and white X) near name varchar(50)..

And when i click execute i got:
#1044 - Access denied for user 'dla_android'@'10.0.0.11' to database 'android_api'

Comment: sounds like you don't have enough privileges for that :)

Comment: I did everything from the beginning and it works, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the accepted answer is enough. This is a very small idea to share after running into the same problem as you report it, but in a beginner's tutorial [Load PostgreSQL Sample Database](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/load-postgresql-sample-database/) in an SQL Shell.

In general, if you have the reported error in an SQL shell, and if you are not sure whether you have typed `;` at the end of the last line, just type `;` as a new command and press Enter to be sure that you type your next command in `LINE 1` and not in `LINE 2`.

Without this "trick", some stupidity like this can happen:

```
postgres=# CREATE DATABASE dvdrental
postgres-# show databases
postgres-# create database dvdrental;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near »show«
LINE 2: show databases
         ^
postgres=# create database dvdrental
postgres-# CREATE DATABASE dvdrental;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near »CREATE«
LINE 2: CREATE DATABASE dvdrental;
         ^
postgres=# CREATE DATABASE dvdrental;
CREATE DATABASE
```

Finally working, as can be seen by the output `CREATE DATABASE`.

Comment: Ok, definitely as a beginner, I can't see why and where's this error coming from. But this solved!